# How can I use was sso login and sso-sessions with serverless-better-credentials serverless plugin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I get `ProcessCredentialsProviderFailure: Profile default not found` when trying to run `ProcessCredentialsProviderFailure: Profile default not found` which does not seem right sense my `~/.aws/config` looks like this:

```
[sso-session aphexlog]
sso_start_url = https://aphexlog.awsapps.com/start
sso_region = us-west-2
sso_registration_scopes = sso:account:access
[profile elevator-robot]
sso_session = aphexlog
sso_account_id = 12345678910
sso_role_name = AWSAdministratorAccess
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

**serverless.json**:

```
service: dog
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x

functions:
  dog:
    handler: index.handler

plugins:
  - serverless-better-credentials
```

**steps to reproduce**:

1. run `npm i --save-dev serverless-better-credentials`
2. run `aws sso login --profile elevator-robot`
3. run `serverless info --aws-profile elevator-robot`
4. then you get the error

*However, if I just export all my env variables (secret keys) then it works fine*